# How do people who do not speak Indian English "prepone" things?

Tags: word-choice, indian-english

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepone),

**Prepone** is an Indian English word which means "to move to an earlier time", used as an antonym to "postpone". For example:

> "The publication date has been preponed from July to June".

Interestingly, it also mentions that *the word is largely unheard outside the subcontinent*.

So, my question is, what word or phrase do the natives outside Indian English speaking ones use to imply the same thing ? Is it simply "moved" or something else?

Comment: One usage that is sometimes heard in some areas of the US is "the date has been ***advanced*** to..."

Comment: Btw, Indian English has hundreds of thousands of native speakers, so you shouldn't draw a contrast between "native speakers" and speakers of Indian English.

Comment: Maybe the word is seldom heard in the US because we are so good at procrastinating over here ;-)

Comment: @rjpond, Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say "brought forward".

Cambridge has [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bring-forward-something) for **bring forward**:

> to change the schedule of something so that it happens earlier:
>
> *He agreed to bring forward deadlines for reducing phosphates in the lake.*

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to say that the meeting has been **moved up** or **moved forward**.

For example,

> [The meeting has been moved up to 3 April 2012...](http://sos.ri.gov/documents/publicinfo/omdocs/notices/46/2012/120892.pdf)
>
> [The meeting is normally on Tuesday but there is an event at the club that day so the meeting has been moved forward one day.](http://www.bemidjigolf.com/e-letter/10-01-08.html)